# Spring MVC 2.5: how to load properties file

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I need to load many properties files, which are in the resources folder.

I have a resource called abc_en.properties with the content below:
      `a = x

       b = y

       c = z`

and I need to use the properties sing java.util.Properties in a Java Method:

```
  java.util.Properties reportProperties = new java.util.Properties();   
   ...
  String a = reportProperties.getProperty("a");
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: I am looking for the best solution. I have a resource called xyz_en.properties and I need to use the properties defined in this one, using java.util.Properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the propertyConfigurer bean in your context file:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:abc.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:efg.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**EDIT:**

In order to use `java.util.Properties` you need to define the `PropertiesFactoryBean` bean in your context file :

```
    <bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
          <property name="location">
               <list>
                 <value>classpath:abc_en.properties</value>
                 <value>classpath:abc_fr.properties</value>
               </list>
          </property>
        </bean>
```

Then in your class you need to define a `java.util.Properties` varible and load the properties bean into it :

```
public class MyClass {

     @Autowired
     private java.util.Properties properties;


     public void myMethod() {
         String a = properties.getProperty("a");
         String b = properties.getProperty("b");
         String c = properties.getProperty("c");
     }
}
```

There are other ways to load the properties bean into you class, but if you use the `@Autowired` annotation, you need to put the `<context:annotation-config />` element in you context file.

Comment: You can assign the property to a variable in the class like if you have in your properties file `my.application.variable=something`, you can define a spring bean like:  

`<bean class="my.class">
<property name="variable" value="${my.application.variable}"/>
</bean>`

Comment: So, is it necessary to have a bean for each .properties? And a field for each property?

Comment: Thanks, I am trying the solution but now I have another problem  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653373/spring-mvc-2-5-load-property-propertiesfactorybean-return-null

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the messagesource bean in your xml file.

Try this way

```
<bean id="messageSource" name="applicationMessageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
      <list>
          <value>resources.abc.abc</value>
       </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```