# Getting value in .properties file directly from Spring context

Tags: spring

In a standard Spring application, a  PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer may be defined, which will load one or more property files. The values defined in the files will then be visible to the rest of the application, both in XML (`"${}"`) and Java (`@Value`).

Is there a way, once a context has been loaded, to get such a property value from the context itsef, in the similar way that a bean can be retrieved (`ctx.getBean("bean-name")`) ?

I tried the following, but it does not work:

```
GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
ctx.load("classpath:META-INF/spring/spring-context.xml");
ctx.refresh();
ctx.start();
ctx.getEnvironment().getProperty("key-name")); // RETURNS NULL
```

Thanks

Comment: Check out http://java.dzone.com/articles/properties-spring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get access to the `BeanFactory`:

```
ctx.getBeanFactory().resolveEmbeddedValue("${key-name}");
```

Comment: does not work with Spring 5 anymore, sadly, methods are not available and I did not find a replacement.

Comment: You can use Environment:
`env.resolvePlaceholders("${key-name:default-value}")`
To inject Environment your class can implement `EnvironmentAware` or you can Environment from from `ApplicationContext`, as it's extending `EnvironmentCapable` class.

Answer (score 2):

See this answer for a simple approach that could work by adding an interface called EmbeddedValueResolverAware to the class in which you want to resolve the property values.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16106729/1325237

Comment: this is the only way that worked for me in a simple way with Spring 5, without having to wrap any Spring classes.

Answer (score 0):

The embedded variable can be retrieved from the `Environment` by using the `resolvePlaceholders` method.  Note that you need to wrap it in `${}`:

```
ctx.getEnvironment().resolvePlaceholders("${key-name}")
```